# Code Signing error when building on device

Tags: ios, xcode, intents-extension

I am just trying to run the [test code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html)
on the Apple Dev site for CallKit and can get the code to run fine on the onscreen simulator, but not on my actual iPhone X external device. I am getting the error Code Signing Error:

> Signing for "IntentsExtension" requires a development team. Select a
>   development team in the project editor.  Code Signing Error: Code
>   signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 11.3'

I've read that the intents extension is for Siri, and not sure how that's involved in this demo. I am signed into my developer account. I tried updating my phone OS. What else should I try?

Comment: You can change the bundle id to `com.yourname.anythingyouwant` for test in real device

Comment: @QuocNguyen changed it to `com.doug.anythingiwant` with no results. What should `yourname` be? My xcode profile name?

Comment: you can choose a unique bundleId, and change the develop team to your account

Comment: @QuocNguyen Sorry, I'm not sure what you meant there, but I changed the Bundle ID to com.douglasrcjames.SpeakerBox which should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQOND.png)

make sure

- two targets have the same bundle identifier prefix. such as
     `us.forus.apple-samplecode.blablabla`.
- the signing team can't be blank

Comment: That screenshot did it, I wasn't looking at the Targets dropdown menu in the upper left of the Project file. I needed to add my developer account to both the IntentsExtension and the Speakerbox targets